# ScanSnap s1300i "unable to connect ... due to an error in the program's operating environment" 0x80004005

Tags: windows-10, hardware-failure

Ever since upgrading to Windows 10 I am getting this error:

```
Unable to connect with ScanSnap due to an error in the program's operating environment.  (0x80004005)

Uninstall ScanSnap Manager, and then install it again.
```

Problem is, I've done this several times, which fixes it temporarily, but eventually it will screw up again.  Unplugging / plugging back in doesn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me provide by the user Daco on [DocumentSnap](http://www.documentsnap.com/scansnap-windows-10/). I've modified the steps for recent Windows 10 editions.

1. Right click on the Task Bar and open Task Manager
2. Select the Services tab and click Open Services at the bottom
3. Find the service named *Windows Image Acquisition (WIA)*, right-click on it and select Properties
4. Select the Log On tab, and click *Local System account* (it's likely that *This account* is selected and Local Service is the name that is entered)
5. Ensure that *Allow service to interact with desktop* is also checked.
6. Click OK
7. Restart your system (it's also possible that restarting the service is sufficient)

At this point, the blue light on the scanner changed from flashing to solid blue and I was able to use it without further problems. NOTE: I had tried and returned an Epson scanner recently which had a similar problem. I'm guessing it was due to the same cause.

Comment: can confirm just restarting the service and scansnap manager fixed this for me.  thank you thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the computer allowed it to connect properly again.  Not ideal, but worked.

Comment: So do you consider the problem solved or is it recurring and you're still looking for a permanent solution?